# ASP.NET MVC - Email sending via website or WCF service

Tags: wcf, email

My website uses WCF services. I need to design an email sending module. I am planning to send email from the website itself, users will get instant emails. I send emails via Mandril.

But the other option is to use a scheduled agent process to send emails. Periodically check the database for email sending entries and send. If email sending fails, system will try again.

What is the best approach for this? My website has user registration, password reset, monthly notification emails etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not great idea to send email directly from the website unless you have very few users and very fast and reliable email server. Also retrying could be tricky.

Better solution would be to use a queue. Website will put email tasks in the queue, another process will check the queue for tasks and send the emails.

Comment: Hi would a WCF with a queue suffice for this feature?